# Question about data access

Tags: 2010

I am creating an application for SharePoint Server 2010. The application will run on a remote computer. I need to identify a data access method to query lists in the application. Strongly-typed access to columns must be provided from within Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. Which method should I use?

client access objec modeL?
linq to sharepoint
rest
or the server object model

I think it shoud be linq to sharepoint, but its in a remote computer I dont know
I know that with rest I can do it, but is REST for strongly typed accesS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your two constraints 1) Accessing SharePoint Data Remotely 2) Access the data in strongly typed fashion, "ADO.NET Data Services (aka WCF data services) is the best bet.

Refer to following resources (videos) to understand and evaluate various Data Access technologies:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff420381.aspx

http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/matthijs/Remote-Data-Access-in-SharePoint-2010